# Bootstrap 3 button/textbox vertical align without label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, label, vertical-alignment

Using bootstrap 3, how to align vertically and put a button at the bottom when it doesn't have a label above his column?

Like this situation:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label class="control-label">Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 ">
            <div class="text-center">                
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Swap!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label class="control-label">Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used mainly three solutions:

1. Using 2 rows (one for the labels and one for the textbox and buttons) like https://jsfiddle.net/luancaius/7ygoys11/. This solution is not responsive and create some layout problems.
2. Using margin-top on the middle column. Also has responsive problems.
3. Using a label with non-breaking space, which fix the problem, but it doesn't look very good. This is my current solution.
   https://jsfiddle.net/luancaius/mr5wLoxf/

Does anyone have a better way to fix this? Or am I doing the layout structure wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first solution seems fit for purpose. What about it is not responsive and what layout problems are you having with it?

Comment: If you resize the layout, you should get labels above fields and one field alone. Using the first solution you get all the labels together (first row) and then the fields together (second row). Is there a way to show this in jsfiddle?

Comment: I've played around with your first solution and it seems to do what you're requesting. The labels are on their own row above the button and inputs, regardless of how narrow you make the viewport. As far as vertical alignment goes, I don't see the issue. Perhaps I misunderstood your question

Comment: The problem happens when you have a lot of fields and need to change some of then from col-md-3 to col-xs-12 for example. The first row will split and the labels won't be align with their inputs. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/luancaius/k05qgesj/ , On small screen won't work.

Comment: How about this? I use transparent labels as a quick way to maintain consistency in vertical alignment between the label-less buttons and the fields. I use only one row like some of your solutions. https://jsfiddle.net/k05qgesj/1/

Comment: fixed the link https://jsfiddle.net/k05qgesj/3/

Comment: Interesting solution, better then using non-breaking space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aligning with vertical-align:

```
.col-xs-3 {display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; float:none;}
```

Just make sure there are no spaces in the html between the each of the col-xs-3 divs. Or use a comment to divide them, like this:

```
<div>...</div><!--  space   --><div>...</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yw0a6689/

**UPDATE:** Instead of doing this for every column, you can do it generally like this:

```
.container > .row > div {display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; float:none;}
```

Or more specific by giving the row a class like .myrow and then declaring:

```
.myrow > div {display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; float:none;}
```

Comment: But I would need to do this for every type of bootstrap col? Like col-xs-1, col-xs-2, col-sm-3...?